# Multiple datetime fields for a model in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a log system to register some faults I need to handle at my work. I use Django and my models look like these:

```
class Chan(models.Model):
    channelname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    freq = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.channelname)

# timestamp object
class EventTime(models.Model):
    since = models.DateTimeField()
    till = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.since.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

class Fault(models.Model):
    channel = models.ManyToManyField(Chan)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="-")
    message = models.TextField()
    timeevent = models.ManyToManyField(EventTime,null=True)
    visible = models.BooleanField()
```

Firstly I used just one EventTime object but I soon realized I need to be able to choose several time periods because the same event could happen several times a day. So it would be too tedious to create a new record of Fault each time. So I basically needed something like this:

[image: example]

The problem is that 'ManyToManyField' is too unhandy to use because I don't need to keep these values for other faults. So I don't know what solution I can use for it. I don't know how many time periods I need. Maybe I could add an extra Text field to my table where I would keep comma-separated datetime objects converted into a string like '2017-11-06 18:36,2017-11-06 18:37'. But I don't know where to set this extra-conversion because I want to use a standart DateTimeField in Django admin site to set it before I make this conversion. Or maybe I could change the interface itself and add some Javascript. Maybe someone could give me advice or share some useful links. Thank you.

Comment: How the data will pop up? Entered manually or automatically based on logs?

Comment: Manually, this is why I want to use DateTimeField. It's quite handy to choose

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [Many-to-one relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) together with [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for the django admin.

**models.py**

```
class Fault(models.Model):
    channel = models.ManyToManyField(Chan)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="-")
    message = models.TextField()
    visible = models.BooleanField()

class EventTime(models.Model):
    since = models.DateTimeField()
    till = models.DateTimeField()
    fault = models.ForeignKey(Fault, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='timeevents')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.since.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Fault, EventTime
from django.contrib import admin

class EventTimeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = EventTime

@admin.register(Fault)
class FaultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    inlines = [EventTimeInline,]
```